# ANTLR4 - multiple code blocks in lexer rule

Tags: antlr4

In ANTLR v3 there was possible to add multi code blocks in one lexer rule, but in version 4 this is not 
allowed. What is the best way to replace this ?

```
TAG
:    '{' (~('}'))* '}'
     { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1)); }
|    '{!{' (options {greedy=false;} : .)* '}!}'
     { setText(getText().substring(3, getText().length()-3)); }     
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is [supposed to be] available [starting with ANTLR 4.2.1](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/releases). If it is not working, you should [file an issue for the project](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues).

Comment: Yes, it works. Problem concerns ANTLR Works 2.1, it displays errors  on this lines, but grammar file is successfuly compiled on ANTLR v 4.4.

Comment: I suggest updating to [ANTLRWorks 2.4.1](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53652/antlrworks-2) using the **Plugins** dialog (Tools &rarr; Plugins)